# Converting SQL to Relational Algebra Example

Tags: sql, database, relational-algebra

I wrote this SQL statement and want to figure out its relational algebra:

```
SELECT S.Oid
FROM Shipment S
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT W.Wid
FROM Warehouse W
WHERE W.City = ‘Pittsburgh’ AND S.Wid = W.Wid)
```

Is this the correct relational algebra for the statement?

> (π S.Oid (Shipment S)) U (π W.City = ‘Pittsburgh’, S.Wid = W.Wid
>   (Warehouse W))

Comment: PLEASE: *Which* version of relational algebra?

Answer (score 2):

Your algebra expression is not correct.

To find the correct answer you can note that the SQL query is equivalent to a join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT S.Oid
FROM Shipment S, Warehouse W
WHERE S.Wid = W.Wid AND W.City = ‘Pittsburgh’
```

so in relational algebra this is equivalent to:

π<sub>S.Oid</sub>(Shipment s ⨝<sub>S.Wid = W.Wid</sub> σ<sub>W.City = ‘Pittsburgh’</sub>(Warehouse W))

Comment: Thank you so much. Okay for something similar like this, would it be like this?

`SELECT I.Iid, I.Unit_Price
FROM Item I, Orders O
WHERE O.Oid = ‘13452’`

As this: 
π I.Iid, I.Unit_Price (Item I ⨝ σ O.Oid = ‘13452’ (Orders O))

Comment: In the SQL query the join condition is missing, so the query is a cross-product instead that a join. Your relational expression is correct, a part that you should use the product × instead of join ⨝.

Comment: Renzo means that your comment SQL should be something like `... AND I.Iid = O.Iid`. @Renzo It doesn't make sense to discuss join vs product here or even the correct algebra expression because it's not clear how column names are handled by the OP's operators: there is no common algebra whose syntax is so SQLy as the OP's or your "algebra" expressions, and the OP hasn't referenced one.